# Ruby rails - undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a small search form to search a user in ldap. It doesn't really have anything to do with local data model. Not sure why do I need any changes in the user controller. The error is not giving any clue to me.

Model - function to search in ldap

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :role, :misc, :password

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :role, :on => :create
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :email

  ROLES = ['Admin','User']

####################
  SERVER = '10.10.10.1'   
  PORT = 389                    
  BASE = 'DC=User,DC=mysite,DC=com'   
  DOMAIN = 'ldap.mysite.com'       
####################

  def self.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticate(login, pass)
     user = find_by_user_id(login)

     if user
     nil
     else
     return false
     end
        conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                         :port => PORT,
                         :base => BASE,
                         :auth => { :username => "#{login}@#{DOMAIN}",
                                    :password => pass,
                                    :method => :simple }
        if conn.bind
        return user
        else
        return false
        end
        rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
        return false
end

  def self.findActiveDirectory(login)
        conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                         :port => PORT,
                         :base => BASE,
                         :auth => { :username => 'admin',
                                    :password => 'adminpass',
                                    :method => :simple }

if  conn.bind
        conn.search(:base => BASE, :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "sAMAccountName", login ),
        :attributes => ['givenName','SN','mail'], :return_result => true) do |entry|
        entry.each do |attributes, values|

        if "#{attributes}" == "sn"
        values.each do |value|
        puts "Lastname: "+"#{value}"
        $lastname = "#{value}"
        end
        end

        if "#{attributes}" == "givenname"
        values.each do |value|
        puts "Firstname: "+"#{value}"
        $firstname = "#{value}"
        end
        end

        if "#{attributes}" == "mail"
        values.each do |value|
        puts "Email: "+"#{value}"
        $email = "#{value}"
        end
        end

        end
        end

    return true
    else
    return false
    end

    rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
    return false
   end

end
```

User controller -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_added_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

View - is NOT working (app/views/users/find.html.erb)

```
<h1>Find User</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

View - is working (app/views/users/new.html.erb)

```
<h1>Add new user</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :Username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :Firstname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :Lastname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Role %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => false %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

routes -

```
# rake routes
  myapp_new GET    /myapp/new(.:format)          myapp#new
        root        /                            home#index
sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
   users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
 users_added GET    /users/added(.:format)       users#added
      myapp GET    /myapp(.:format)              myapp#new
     log_out GET    /log_out(.:format)           sessions#destroy
      log_in GET    /log_in(.:format)            sessions#new
     sign_up GET    /sign_up(.:format)           users#new
  users_find GET    /users/find(.:format)        users#find
        root        /                            users#new
       users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
    sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          sessions#index
             POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
     session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#show
             PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
```

Error -

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Comment: On what line in your code does the error happen? Where do you call FindActiveDirectory?

Comment: Please provide the full backtrace from the error and the relevant code excerpts from your app it references.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall 
`Started GET "/users/find" for 10.110.34.12 at 2012-04-05 03:31:57 -0400
Processing by UsersController#find as HTML
  Rendered users/find.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method ``model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <h1>Find User</h1>
    2:
    3: <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    4:   <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    5:     <div class="error_messages">
    6:       <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
  app/views/users/find.html.erb:3:in` `_app_views_users_find_html_erb__964737868_89494140'`

Comment: @Mischa,  I dont have FindActiveDirectory directly anywhere yet. Honestly, didn't finish that part. I am stuck with this error.

Comment: @mosch, directly through the user /users/find

Comment: Can you post the view filename, the action and the relevant routes?

Comment: @mosch, directly through the url /users/find

Comment: @mosch, `# rake routes | grep user
   users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
 users_added GET    /users/added(.:format)       users#added
     sign_up GET    /sign_up(.:format)           users#new
  users_find GET    /users/find(.:format)        users#find`

Comment: @mosch,         `root        /                            users#new
       users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy`

Comment: @Mischa, Did you mean to add `@user = User.new` in the user controller file or somewhere else? It is already there in user controller file.

Comment: Basically I am trying to add a new feature of searching a user in ldap under the standard built user view and controller.

Comment: @FirstnameLastname, could you add this information to the question? That's much more readable than adding it as a comment? Did you see my answer? Does it help you?

Comment: Yes, I meant in the controller file. I tried to explain some more in the update to my answer. It seems you are very new to Rails. I recommend checking out [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org), which teaches you a lot of the Rails basics.

Comment: Furthermore, it seems to me that Mischa is right so @user is never set to any value because Rails is using the (implicitly defined) 'find' action, which doesn't do anything by default but rendering the view. If you don't have that action, then add it, if not, please post its code!

Comment: @mosch. I edited my question to add some more code, there is one more view in users that works perfectly.

Comment: @FirstnameLastname, thanks for the update. My answer explains why you get the error and how to get rid of it. Did you try? Is there something you don't understand about it? Please let me know.

Comment: @Mischa, thank you both. that solved it! Came up with a new issue, but I shall be able to fix that on my own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `@user` in your view, but `@user` is defined nowhere and thus `nil`. That's why you get this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

To solve this you have to add the following to your controller:

```
def find
  @user = User.new
end
```

Or change your view like this:

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
```

This will get rid of the error you are getting, but submitting this form will post to your create action, which is not what you want. For searching you'd better use [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag). Check out [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for form basics. Basically `form_for` is for creating and updating data, which does not apply to searching.