# Undefined method 'model_name' for nil:Nil Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, config

So i followed Ryan Bates Screencasts on using Paypal basic for payments and everything worked fine in development. However, when i deployed to Heroku and tried it. I got an `Undefined method 'model_name' for nil:Nil`.

It seems its breaking on the form_for in the cart page.

```
  <%= form_tag APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url] do %>
  <% end %>
```

<strike>For some reason, it is not loading the variable `APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url]`. I generated it using nifty:config as done in the tutorial.</strike>

**UPDATE**

It is infact loading the APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url]. Looked into the heroku console and found it is loading the variable but says `undefined method 'model_name' for nil:Nil Class`

I've tried removing `APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url]` and replacing it with the actual url, but it still says the same thing.

Works all good in development, but not on Heroku. Am i doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

**Backtrace:**

```
   Rendered customer/carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.6ms)
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.046130+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server                  Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 16.5ms)
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047088+00:00 app[web.1]: 
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047099+00:00 app[web.1]:     38: 
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047097+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error     (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047098+00:00 app[web.1]:     37:       <%= button_to          'Empty cart', @cart, action: 'destroy', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you   sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-default empty_cart btn_stand' %><br>
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047101+00:00 app[web.1]:     41:       <%= hidden_field_tag :size, value: :size %>
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047100+00:00 app[web.1]:     39:       <%= form_tag APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url] do %>
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047100+00:00 app[web.1]:     40:       <%= fields_for LineItem.find_by(params[:id]) do %>
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047101+00:00 app[web.1]:     42:       <%= hidden_field_tag :color, value: :color %>
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047104+00:00 app[web.1]: 
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047103+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/customer/carts/show.html.erb:39:in `_app_views_customer_carts_show_html_erb__1117899742375249126_70196778419380'
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047102+00:00 app[web.1]:     43:       <% end %>
   2016-06-18T07:40:46.047103+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/customer/carts/show.html.erb:40:in `block in _app_views_customer_carts_show_html_erb__1117899742375249126_70196778419380'
```

Comment: Would you please paste the backtrace? Or paste some code that calling `model_name`

Comment: Could this answer solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023353/ruby-rails-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass

Comment: @scorix No, it can't. `APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url]` is a link as shown in the config file. It also works completely fine locally. Just not on Heroku..

Comment: what happens when you properly indent `yml` file?

Comment: Can I have a look at `show` method in `CartsController`? In my opinion, if `@cart` is already deleted, refreshing this page would also cause this error. You can have a try.

Comment: @scorix @cart hasn't been deleted, this happens when clicking Cart for the first time. If there was a problem with the `show` method in the CartsController, would it work locally?

Comment: @oreoluwa the yml file is properly indented. Lost the formatting after posting on StackOverflow

Comment: @scorix According to the backtrace - `app/views/customer/carts/show.html.erb:39:in `_app_views_customer_carts_show_html_erb__1117899742375249126_70196778419380'` - **Line 39**: `<%= form_tag APP_CONFIG[:paypal_url] do %>`
- Thats why i think thats what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I think I've found the problem you're having. Could you check the value of your `@cart` variable, as it seems it's `nil`. Could you post your controller instantiating your `@cart`?

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I'm not totally sure, but what happens when you do this:

```
development: &default
  paypal_email: xxxxx@xxxx.com
  paypal_secret: xxxxxx
  paypal_cert_id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
  paypal_url: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Also, you don't really need the nifty config generator, Rails already provides a convenient method for loading ENV dependent configurations

```
#{Your Application Name}::Application.config_for(:app_config)
```

Or even better, you could use [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for your configurations

**UPDATE**

To use the rails provided config method, you could have something like:

```
#config/initializers/paypal_config.rb
PaypalConfig = #{Your Application Name}::Application.config_for(:app_config)
```

Wherever you need the config, you could now use:

```
PaypalConfig[:paypal_url] #instead of the APP_CONFIG
```

Comment: Should i delete the `load_app_config` initializer generated by the nifty:generator cause locally, it seems thats what is loading the file but doesn't seem to work on Heroku. Also the yml file is called `app_config.yml`. How do i load that in the config file?

Comment: honestly I don't know what the reason for the error might have been, if you've tried the approach above. Have you tried to use Figaro for this? You could delete the load_app_config; adding a snippet for a new file in my answer above

Comment: But i'll still keep the `app_config.yml` file right?

Comment: yes. the method infers the config file from the argument

Comment: Still doesn't work. Doesn't load the file, so the form in the view never gets loaded. I wrote `<%= form_tag PaypalConfig[:paypal_url] do %>` and it doesn't work...
When i click submit, there's a routing error because the form never gets submitted

Comment: if the project is on a public Github, I could help take a look. Can't really say why this may be happening

Comment: Its not public, but if you send your email address, i could add you to the repo

Comment: github.com/andela-oakinniranye

Comment: I just updated my answer. Could you post your controller serving this view? As I assume the @cart variable is nil..